# jQuery getJSON data into modal form div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a MVC application, trying fill a bootstrap modal form with data from the server, and to do that I'm trying to do the following:

1) I load a grid with several IDs, each one with a javascript onclick function.

2) The function gets the ID number, and fires an ajax request to the server to get the related data and the ID as parameter.

3) The resulting JSON is supposed to be displayed in the modal body.

So far I got the 1 and 2 items working, but I can't seem to make the modal form display the data I retrieve from the server. I've tried changing the $.getJSON for a $.ajax, and changing the div tag with a paragraph or header (supposing a string for example would fit just fine), but with no luck. I even tried replacing the div filling method with an alert, just to see the result json, but that also didn't work.

This is my code:

View (only the modal part):

```
<div id="modalZoomOperaciones" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" data-url='@Url.Action("OperacionDetalle")'>
<div id="contenido">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class=" modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">@Global.Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="response"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@Global.BackToList</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS function:

```
function showDetails(oper_numero) {

    var url = $('#modalZoomOperaciones').data('url');

    $.getJSON({
        url: url,
        data: { operacion: oper_numero },
        success: function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        }
    });

    $("#modalZoomOperaciones").modal({ backdrop: "static" });
}
```

Controller (I know it has unnecesary code and redundancies. It's a testing enviroment, not the actual development site):

```
public JsonResult OperacionDetalle(int operacion)
    {
        IEnumerable<OperacionesTestViewModel> datos = UnitOfWork.ExecuteSpScript.spOperacionesDetalleTest(operacion);
        OperacionesTestViewModel datos1 = datos.FirstOrDefault();
        return Json(datos1);
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the success callback get executed? Try adding a console.log() to see if it gets called. If it does get called then, output the data to the console.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem involved MVC security, I got the data but I wasn't able to bring it to the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is stuck with this, changing the $.getJSON for a $.ajax type 'POST' is NOT a solution, since there is no transaction involved.

As MVC protects the application from a particular type of JSON request attack, there is something that has to be added in the controller action:

Instead of this:

```
return Json(data);
```

It has to be like this:

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```